# Indy Telnet SendString robustness best practice

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, telnet, indy

I have a simple Firemonkey application with a series of buttons and sliders (track bar) that when a user interacts with these controls it send a command using IdTelnet. i.e.

```
IdTelnet1.SendString(' '+str+#13);
```

The problem is that very occasionally the users experience total lockup of the app and windows reports the app as "Not responding" when clicking on something. I have not reproduced this myself however I suspect its related to clicking on buttons in quick succession.

My current theory is that I am getting re-entry into SendString and IdTelnet is not handling this well.

Before jumping into writing a queued sending system I wanted to ask for any best practice advice. Is this a known issue and what is the best way to do quick fire sends that are user initiated?

Comment: This is not a reentry issue if you are calling `SendString()` in the main UI thread, which will serialize the button clicks (and thus serialize the sends). Since TCP connections can block (and Indy does use blocking sockets), you should not perform blocking operations in the main UI thread to begin with. Move the Telnet traffic to a secondary worker thread instead, and then have the UI notify that thread when it needs to send things.

Comment: Thanks. I have created a message queue processed in its own thread. Hopefully this will make things more robust.